# Spell Check app or setting while using drop down keyboard

Tags: keyboard, spell-check

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get word completion with physical keyboard?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4574/how-can-i-get-word-completion-with-physical-keyboard)

Is there anyway to get spell check functionality while using the drop down keyboard?

Comment: Do you mean "slide out" keyboard, like on the Droid?

Answer (score 1):

Most keyboards come with suggestions for common words, so a spell check function is rendered moot. Once a user types a couple of letters, the most common words containing those letters usually show up in a bar above the on screen keyboard.

Most keyboards like Smart Keyboard / Better keyboard also have options that allow for word suggestion to show up if a user opts for the hardware keyboard instead of the "soft" on-screen keyboard.