# How can I get word completion with physical keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, input-methods

Is there any app or method that provides word completion when using a physical keyboard?

Comment: No one's come up with an answer, but I think your question may be a better worded version of this one: "Spell Check app or setting while using drop down keyboard"  http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2254/spell-check-app-or-setting-while-using-drop-down-keyboard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe [Better Keyboard](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.betterandroid.betterkeyboard8) and [Smart Keyboard Pro](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.cdeguet.smartkeyboardpro) offer suggestions even with the use of the hardware keyboard. This is a user configurable feature available in the app settings.